# filter pandas dataframe by index, selection criteria and select columns all in one

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with stock prices from multiple stocks.

I am able to filter the dataframe so that it only shows stock_name = "BHP", and so that it only shows this months data.

When I load the dataframe (df) it has many columns. But I only need the close column and the index to graph. How can I add to this query so that what is selected is:

1) stock_name  == BHP
2) dates = september
3) AND only the 1] "close" and the 2] index are shown (index is already datetime index)

This one line query satisfies criteria one and two:

```
bhp = df[(df["stock_name"]=="BHP")]["2015-09-01":"2015-09-25"]
```

However when I try for the third adding a  list of columns to the end I get a series not a dataframe with an index for plotting:

```
bhp = df[(df["stock_name"]=="BHP")]["2015-09-01":"2015-09-25"]["close"]
```

I have the date as the index and it's own column if that helps.

Comment: Does `bhp = df.loc[(df["stock_name"]=="BHP"), "close"].loc["2015-09-01":"2015-09-25"]` give you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of this at work.  When working with stocks and time dimensions we generally use `DATExSTOCKxVALUE` concept.  Where your columns are stocks and your index is dates and the values are for a single factor.  Close prices would just be a timeseries with the columns are the stock_names.

Turn this:

```
date        stock    close
2015-08-31   ibm      1.0
2015-08-31   aapl     1.0
2015-08-31   goog     1.0
2015-08-31   bhp      1.0
....
```

Into this (the values are only "close" prices)

```
date        aapl    ibm    goog    bhp    ...
2015-08-31   1.0    1.0     1.0    1.0    ...
2015-08-31   1.0    1.0     1.0    1.0    ...
```

Try this type of code:

```
close_px = df.set_index(['date', 'stock_name'])['close']  # Multiindex Series
bhp = close_px.unstack(level='stock_name')['BHP']  # Stocks as columns, timeseries index, then subset to BHP
res = bhp.loc["2015-09-01", "2015-09-25"]  # Access the rows like a standard timeseries
```

If you have multiple stocks, the second line gives you a close price timeseries that you can access by stock name very easily.